# the code doesn't work properly at output C

Tags: c

I tried to read 2 variables from the keyboard and to write them on the screen and I have a problem, the program display me only one..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    short int n,x;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%d %d",n,x);
    return 0;
}
```

I introduced 14 and 15 and the program return me 0 and 15
can somebody tell me why?

Comment: Make the variables of data type `int` - `int n,x;` or e use `%hd` instead of `%d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use %hd format specifier for short int
Use %hu format specifier for unsigned int
Use %d format specifier for int
Use %ld format specifier for long int

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  short int n, x;
  scanf("%hd", &n); // Notice %hd instead of %d for short int
  scanf("%hd", &x); // Notice %hd instead of %d for short int
  printf("%hd%hd", n, x);// Notice %hd instead of %d for short int
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The formatters in `scanf()` and `printf()` doesn't match the type of your variables `n` and `x`.

`%d` uses the variables as they were `int` while `int` has probably the double number of bytes as `short int`. ([Integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Integer_types))

Hence, with the wrong formatters, `scanf()` uses the provided addresses wrong. 
For `printf()` it's a bit more complicated: The `short int`s are converted to `int` internally. ([Default argument promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions)) Hence, printing `short int` with `%d` (as they were `int`) doesn't fail.

So, it's the `scanf()` what *must* be fixed.

Either use correct formatters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    short int n,x;
    scanf("%hd",&n);
    scanf("%hd",&x);
    printf("%d %d",n,x);
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/K0RMQk)</kbd>

or use correct variable type for the formatters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,x;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%d %d",n,x);
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/5E2PsR)</kbd>

The formatting of `scanf()` and `printf()` families are very powerful and flexible but unfortunately very error-prone as well. Using them wrong introduces [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939). The compiler is (usually) unable to recognize errors as the evaluation of formatters happens at run-time and inside the `scanf()`/`printf()` functions. So, they have to be used caaarefully.

Answer (score 1):

`%d` assumes the variable to be of data type `int`.

Use the data type `int`:

```
int main()
{
    int n,x;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%d %d",n,x);
    return 0;
}
```

or use `%hd` instead of `%d`

```
int main()
{
    short int n,x;
    scanf("%hd",&n);
    scanf("%hd",&x);
    printf("%hd %hd",n,x);
    return 0;
}
```

Note, `scanf("%d",&x);` read a value and stores it to the memory addressed by `&x`. Since `&x` is treated as a 4 byte memory, 4 bytes are written to the address specified by `&x`.